# SharePoint 2013 Workflow call http web service sync mode

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I would like to know if the SharePoint 2013 workflow "Call Http web service" activity is synchronous or asynchronous ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is synchronous. At least it is synchronous in VS and I don't see any reason why this should be different in SPD. `ResponseContent` is readable immediately after the call.

Comment: Thanks Slaven for your answer. I mean by "Especially in SharePoint Designer" is that could it be configured in SPDesigner or VS to be asynchronous.

Comment: No problem. I don't see how it could be configured as asynchronous. If that was true, you would have to specify a callback function for reading the results.